# Import-CSV outputs the header row as a single property

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I have run into a really annoying problem involving trying to get a specific cell from a csv file using Import-CSV.

I have followed the instructions as far as other answers have shown me:
Let's say we have a csv file with columns named col1, col2, col3, col4 and so on

```
$importedCSV = Import-CSV csvfile.csv
$importedCSV
col1;col2;col3;col4
-------------------
itm1;itm2;itm3;itm4
itm5;itm6;itm7;itm8
```

It seems to work well so far, and if I do `$importedCSV[0]` and `$importedCSV[1]` it will filter out the respective non-selected row like normal.

The problem arises when I try to call a specific cell like `$importedCSV[0].col2`, it wont display anything at all, and if I press tab after the dot, it autocompletes as 'col1;col2;col3;col4', if I do `$importedCSV | Get-Member`, it also displays 'col1;col2;col3;col4' as a single string property, I assume this is what makes it impossible to get a specific cell from the csv file.

Comment: Use `-Delimiter ';'`

Comment: Yep, I realized it after a friend responded to my dms, answering my own query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I found out what the issue was, I'm using Spanish Excel to generate my CSVs which uses `;` instead of `,` as delimiter, the Delimiter has to be manually set to `;` in the powershell command like so:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\csvfile.csv -Delimiter ";"
```

That solves the issue.

Comment: Another option is to specify the delimiter indirectly, via the list separator that applies to the _current culture_ (as reflected in `(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ListSeparator`): `-UseCulture` (instead of `-Delimiter ';'`).